# error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript|

Tags: c++, arrays, types

the code returns error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript| and everything else seems to run fine. What can I do about it ? (line 10,22,23)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n, x[50], y[50], z[50];

void citire(int &n, int v)
{
    int i;
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        cout << "v[" << i << "]=";
        cin >> v[i];
    }
}

void afisare(int n, int v[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << v[i] << " " << endl;
}

void s(unsigned n, int x[], int y[], int z[])
{
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        z[i] = abs(x[i] - y[i]);
}

int main()
{
    cout << "n=";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "x[]:" << endl;
    citire(n, x);
    cout << "y[]:" << endl;
    citire(n, y);
    cout << "Elementele primului vector" << endl;
    afisare(n, x);
    cout << "Elementele celui de-al doilea vector:" << endl;
    afisare(n, y);

    s(n, x, y, z);
    cout << "z[]:" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there some newly instigated monetary penalty for whitespace and indentation to make code readable? I mean, I thought the days of line-editing decwriters was long gone (and good riddance), but I'm seeing this more and more. Without objection (or with), I'm formatting that.. thing. As for the code. I *strongly* advise you stop fighting 0-based indexing and start embracing it. Someone entering `50` for `n` at program start is going to invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: indeed, you should use 0 based indices. Not only you are wasting memory for the element at index 0 that you never use, but once you replace the c-arrays with `std::vector` or any other proper container, all your loops will cause undefined behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `v` as an array, but it isn't an array, it is `int`. You probably want to use `int* v`.

```
void citire(int &n, int* v) {
// ...
cin>>v[i];
}
```